# How to return a lambda function with a parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I have a function template which accept a callable object including a lambda like the below

```
template<class ValueT, class ValidatorF>
void myFun(ValueT& value, ValidatorF validate)
{
    ...
    if (validate(value)) ... // call to validate the value
    ...
}
```

and I can use it like the following with a validator to test if an integer greater than 0 or not

```
int i = 10;
myFun(i, [](int& value) {return value > 0;});
```

Now I want an validater to test if an intger greater than a specific number (not just 0), I do

```
auto greaterThan = [](int number) 
                   { return [number](int& value) { return value > number; }; };
```

But the above cannot compile with VS2013. Any bugs or way to let it work?

I just tested in Coliru. It is okay. Maybe that is due to VS2013. By testing

```
int main()
{
    auto greaterThan = [](int number) 
                       { return [number](int& value) { return value > number; }; };
}
```

The VS2013 compilation error is

> `Error    1   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'main::<lambda_20b9557a9ed9208edabcd15f35d83ad2>::()::<lambda_44761a42f06f1791bdbf89e7a9b3a961>' to 'bool (__cdecl *)(int &)'   main.cpp    8`

Comment: You need a semi-colon. `return [number](int& value) { return value > number; }` **;** (Unless you just typed it in, then that's probably not your real issue.)

Comment: What is your compile error? Maybe the lambda expression needs an return type: [] ( int number ) -> bool .... As far as I remember in some version of MSVC return types need to be explicitly defined.

Comment: @user1899020 As you've already been asked, **please provide the compiler error**. We can't easily help you figure out a workaround if we don't even know why the compiler is upset.

Comment: It compiled ok for me, I tried: `int i = 5;
  auto f = greaterThan(10)(i);`

Comment: @user1899020 Is line 8 the `auto greaterThan` line you are showing, or is it some later line?

Comment: @cdhowie Yes. It is the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what ecatmur said, you can decide to implement an uncurried version of your greaterThan method and use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind the second argument:

```
auto greaterThan = [](int num1, int num2) -> { return num1 > num2; };
myFun(i, std::bind(greaterThan, _1, number) );
```

Comment: @user1899020 It should since it doesn't require the lambda to be called virtually. Further, the compiler can see all the way into the lambda when it's used in a template and therefore it might inline the lambda directly into the instantiation of the template function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a deficiency in MSVC; it can't handle return type deduction to lambda with a non-empty capture-list.

At the cost of some inefficiency, you can use `std::function` to type-erase the lambda:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    auto greaterThan = [](int number) -> std::function<bool(int&)>
        { return [number](int& value) -> bool { return value > number; }; };
}
```